# Postgresql 15 query optimization question - why does a cast fix this?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan

Ever since we upgraded to PG15, we have some queries that just aren't performing well. The optmizer is picking poor strategies even for simple left joins (the exact same query & data in MySQL runs in a second, and 90 seconds in postgres).

I'll boil things down to the smallest part of the query that seems to show the issue. We have

```
select st.claim_number, trans_date, bill_number 
    FROM
        tmp.tmp_state_table_pg st
    INNER JOIN
        wc_level3.pm_medbill_header med_header
    ON st.claim_number = med_header.claim_number
```

tmp.tmp_state_table_pg has a claim_number (varchar(50)) and ref_date (unused here) with 37k rows and no indexes.  medbill_header has claim_number (varchar(30)), some other fields, and a btree index on claim_number. It has 51 million rows.  Here is the explain analyze:

```
Hash Join  (cost=2231073.70..3009689.80 rows=2628370 width=133) (actual time=32253.150..38141.020 rows=142043 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((st.claim_number)::text = (pm_medbill_header.claim_number)::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on tmp_state_table_pg st  (cost=0.00..621.60 rows=17760 width=118) (actual time=0.009..4.882 rows=37495 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1295587.20..1295587.20 rows=50954120 width=23) (actual time=32248.771..32248.772 rows=50917642 loops=1)
        Buckets: 131072  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 7006kB
        ->  Seq Scan on pm_medbill_header  (cost=0.00..1295587.20 rows=50954120 width=23) (actual time=0.005..9822.087 rows=50917642 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.192 ms
Execution Time: 38148.336 ms
```

It seems wrong on the face of it for it not to be using the index for a simple left join. But even stranger is when I cast the claim number to varchar(30)

```
select st.claim_number, trans_date, bill_number 
    FROM
        tmp.tmp_state_table_pg st
    INNER JOIN
        wc_level3.pm_medbill_header med_header
    ON st.claim_number::varchar(30) = med_header.claim_number
    ;
```

it completes almost instantly.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..3291040.77 rows=2628370 width=133) (actual time=0.038..424.089 rows=142043 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on tmp_state_table_pg st  (cost=0.00..621.60 rows=17760 width=118) (actual time=0.010..6.493 rows=37495 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using pm_medbill_header_claim_number_idx on pm_medbill_header  (cost=0.57..183.79 rows=148 width=23) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=4 loops=37495)
        Index Cond: ((claim_number)::text = ((st.claim_number)::character varying(30))::text)
Planning Time: 0.217 ms
Execution Time: 430.805 ms
```

As a side note, if I fix the varchar length definition of tmp_state_table_pg to varchar(30) so they match, it goes back to the slow hash join. It seems to be the possibility of truncation (which never actually happens; it should be 30) that is convincing the query plan to go back to the more efficient index join.

I'm seeing other cases where a simple left join is being passed over for more inefficient choices.  Our infrastructure team just recently upgraded to pg15 from pg11. I wonder if we missed a new parameter we needed to heed (like mysql's max subquery memory usage - also wrecked a bunch of query performance).  Any suggestions on something to look into  would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you `SET enable_hashjoin = off;` and `SET enable_mergejoin = off;`, what is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the original, slow query?

Comment: You can add COSTS, SETTINGS too. Maybe random_page_cost is too high.